# How do I change my name on the Gmail Android app?

Tags: gmail

I changed my name on the computer side, but it did not change my name on the app. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think you need to change it on different platforms. Change on one, should change it on the server.

Comment: thats wht i would of thought but it still has old name on the app. so i thought maybe i needed to unistall and reinstall

Comment: Maybe it might need to be resynced. I don't use the mobile app very frequently so I suggest waiting until somebody comes up with an answer.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2019-02-24 there is a known bug in the Outlook app for Android with changing the "from" display name for gmail accounts. This bug only affects the Outlook app on Android with Gmail accounts.

The issue is that changes to your display name in Google, which appear in your "from" display name in gmail, are not reflected in the Outlook app on Android. It will be reflected everywhere else -- gmail.com, the gmail app, any other email app on the same phone -- but the Outlook Android app does not pick up the new "From" google display name.

I confirmed this by doing a factory reset on my phone, re-installing Outlook, and it still didn't pick up the new display name from Google. Other Android email apps let you specify your FROM display name but unfortunately the Outlook Android app doesn't have this as an option and instead picks it up from Google.

Here's confirmation of the issue from the Outlook Android team:

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clear the cache of the Gmail app (Settings → Apps → All Applications → Gmail → Clear Cache).

If that doesn't help, clear the Gmail app's data as well and sign in again into Gmail(Settings → Apps → All Applications → Gmail → Clear Data).

This, as @SharpSTA said, will force a resync with the servers, and hopefully update your information.